# Dynamic changes to server without restarting server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, grails, ant

I am working on a project which takes 15 min to build and deploy in local server , My problem is i use to work in grails before this , and i am very use to making changes in controllers/servlets and just refresh the page , changes gets reflected without restarting the server , now i would like something similar for this project which is a Java E Application , we use Ant to build the EAR , any input will be highly appreciated , thanks.

Comment: create a Java Dynamic Web Project and set up for instance Apache Tomcat in config of your project

Comment: Have you tried JRebel?

Comment: I haven't tried JRebel , but i will give it a go , thanks Manu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your IDE to handle the deployment of the application to the app server you'll be able to hot deploy most changes into the current running instance. As long as the class structure doesn't change, e.g. no changes to method signatures or new methods it works pretty seamlessly in my experience.

If you want full class reloading capabilities what will live reload classes even with signature changes you need to use a third-party option like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

Comment: Thanks Darren , i already use Hot deploy , didn't like it much but it's still better than nothing , i will give JRebel a go , Thanks Darren